# Why doesn't my leapfrog method conserve the mechanical energy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numerical-methods

I'm trying to implement the leapfrog method as a Python script, where I simply give the program the functions that define the differential equation system, the initial conditions and the number of steps, and it calculates the values of my unknown variables. The code works fine, but I've noticed it doesn't conserve the total energy of the physical system (I tried it with a simple pendulum). This shouldn't happen because, in theory, the method is time-symmetric. Here's the code:

```
import cmath
import math
from numpy import empty, arange, hstack, append, linspace, zeros


def f(function, arg, variable_names):

    N = len(variable_names)

    function = function.replace(variable_names[0], f'({arg[0]})')

    for i in range(N - 1):

        function = function.replace(variable_names[i + 1], f'({arg[1][i]})') 
        #you have to enter the function as a string

    return eval(function) #ATENTION: if your function has a letter which is the same as your variable, 
#change the variable name to another letter. For example, you can't put exp(x) because there's an
#x which is not an argument in the word exp. Change the x for a t, and it will work (t would
#be the new variable_name argument). variable_name MUST also be a string


def leap(function_list, t0, r0, tN, N, variable_names):

    if type(function_list) != list:

        function_list = list(function_list)

    h = (tN - t0)/N

    t = list(arange(t0, tN + h, h))

    if len(t) != N:

        t.pop(-1)

    #Here comes the mathematical part

    M = len(function_list)

    r = empty([M, N], float)

    for j in range(M):

        r[j, 0] = r0[j] #Initial conditions

    r_half = empty([M, N], float)

    for j in range(M):

        r_half[j, 0] = r0[j] + 0.5*h*f(function_list[j], [t0, list(r[:, 0])], variable_names)
        #First iteration with Euler method to calculate the first half integer step

    for i in range(1, N):

        for j in range(M):
            #Leapfrog method iterations to calculate integer and half integer steps.
            r[j, i] = r[j, i - 1] + h*f(function_list[j], [t[i - 1] + 0.5*h, list(r_half[:, i - 1])], variable_names)

        for j in range(M):

            r_half[j, i] = r_half[j, i - 1] + h*f(function_list[j], [t[i], list(r[:, i])], variable_names)



    return t, r

#Now I apply the method to the pendulum

function_list = ['omega', '-98*math.sin(theta)']

t, r = leap(function_list, 0, [math.pi/2, 0], 10, 1000, ['z', 'theta', 'omega'])

#z represents the time variable, I couldn't write "t" because it would interfere with math.sin
#in the f function.


from numpy import cos
from pylab import plot, show
#Here I plot the energy
plot(t, 0.5*(0.1*r[1])**2 + 9.8*0.1*(1 - cos(r[0])))
```

And this is what comes out:

[Leapfrog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP5wB.png)

As you can see, the energy oscillates with time (which is OK according to the leaprog method), but its amplitude also increases linearly with time (it should stay constant).
I feel like the initial iteration for th first half integer step has something to do with the problem, but I don't know how. If I change that line to:

```
r_half[j, 0] = r0[j] + h*f(function_list[j], [t0, list(r[:, 0])], variable_names)
```

This comes out:
[Corrected leapfrog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVmar.png)

Which is a valid result when it comes to the conservation of energy, but it isn't correct (in fact, the error is of order h, more that the leapfrog method itself). 
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

((I changed your code to eliminate the string evaluation so that the ODE evaluation is done in `function` as a vector function. In the theory part I use the transpose of your convention, lists of vectors instead a vector of sequences.))

What you are effectively computing is the two-step Nyström method or central Euler method to step size `h/2`

```
u[i+1] = u[i-1] + h*F(t[i], u[i])
```

where then the leapfrog sequences are the even and odd sub-sequences of `u`.

```
r = u[0::2]  and r_half = u[1::2]
```

As is well known, [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3067795/115115), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3074962/115115),  the method is only weakly stable. This means that the linear mathematical pendulum or harmonic oscillator would behave as expected, however the non-linearity throws the effective eigenvalues slightly outside the imaginary axis and thus allows errors to accumulate. This means especially that the initial error in computing `u[1]=r_half[0]` gets magnified exponentially. While that is also true for the other step errors, due to the symplectic nature of the method these cancel more-or-less out.

*In short*, increase the order of the first step, for instance by using the second order midpoint method,

```
r_half[:, 0] = r0 + 0.5*h*function(t0+0.25*h, r[:, 0]+0.25*h*function(t0,r[:, 0]))
```

and the energy plot reduces to the expected O(h^2) oscillations

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! Great answer and explanation. I hope that my string evaluation wasn't very uncomfortable for you to correct, I did it that way because it was the fastest method if I wanted to apply the function a lot of times with different equations (I'm taking a course in computational physics in college).  Anyway, your solution worked perfectly and it's very easy to implement. Thanks again!

Comment: You should note that the Verlet methods only make sense in a conservative situation, that is, where the acceleration is minus the gradient of a potential function. This would one step further simplify your interface. I don't know what flexibility you expect, passing functions or classes with evaluation methods should be faster and as universal for yourself. You need the string parsing only if you want to make a graphical application or web interface with function input.

Comment: You might also make your code flexible enough to be able to use higher order Verlet-like methods, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_integrator#A_third-order_example